# Simple Ad-Server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, grails, node.js, advertisement-server

I'm in the middle of a project where we have created the backend for handling ad campaigns in Grails and I am trying to figure out the best way to create the ad-server part. I.e. the part that is going to serve the actual ads to the end users (browsers).

In my last three projects I have been using Grails, which I have come to enjoy very much for it's rapid development and good support from the Java community through Spring and Hibernate. However, Grails still has some performance issues, and I'm not sure it is the right choice for this task. I have been looking at other alternatives, but can't decide which way to go. The server needs to be able to handle around a couple of thousand requests per second, plus needs to be robust. The DB structure is as follows (simplified):

```
Ad ==> site, position, percent of view (percent of time the ad is shown)
```

So basically, the Ad Server needs to get the necessary rows from the DB for the specific site and position and choose which Ad to display (depending on percentage).

Bellow are the different choices I am considering (all of which should have multiple instances and use a load balancer).

- **Grails** together with **Redis** and
  **MongoDB** - I haven't found any reports
  on performance with this trio. In my
  previous projects we have found that
  Grails has lots of performance
  issues, a lot of them we have handled
  in different ways, but for an Ad
  Server, I'm not sure it will do.
- **Node.js** together with a key-value
  store - Node.js is supposedly very
  fast, but it would be a bit risky to
  implement it at this stage since it
  is not yet stabilized.
- **Ruby on Rails**    together with a
  key-value store -    Haven't done any
  Ruby on Rails    development yet, but
  from what I can    gather from
  googling around, Ruby on    Rails has
  a lot better performance    than
  Grails.
- **PHP** with a key-value store - Haven't
  done any PHP programming either, but
  there are a lot of big sites using
  PHP that have good performance, so it
  should be considered a good
  alternative.

Any suggestion or recommendations are warmly welcomed.

Comment: How large is the DB? Lines? MBs?

Comment: There should be around 50.000 to 100.000 rows in the db for starters (first year or so).

Comment: I'm curious to know what you chose. I'm facing a similar situation and am starting to do research now. What did you pick, and are you satisfied with the outcome?

Answer (score 3):

Don't serve any images from the application use a CDN for that. As long as the only thing your application has to do is determine what add to display and return the link to the CDN stored ad then you should be fine to serve your thousands of requests per second. Also don't look to serve everything from one server. Load balancing is your friend in an application like this and it is unreasonable to blame *all* performance issues on the framework of choice.

Comment: I forgot to write load balancing, which is of course necessary to ensure availability and increase performance. In the Grails case, how many instances would you say would be needed?

Comment: I would not know really how many instances are needed, that depends on the type of data returned as well as the resources of the server.

Answer (score 2):

100.000 rows is small enough to store in memory.
With node.js I would try out keeping the data in an in-process DB.
Assuming the data set doesn't grow too large, and updates to the DB are infrequent, a very simple node server should yield good performance.

ad.db :

```
{ key:'site:position', value: [{id:'1424234', percent:50}, { id:'8394847', percent:50}] }
```

url :

http:://adserver.com/?add=site:position

adServer.js :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var db = require('dirty')('ad.db');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query.add;
  var adds = db.get(query);
  var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );
  var id = '';
  for( var i = 0, len = adds.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if( random < adds[i].percent ) {
      id = adds[i].id;
      break;
    } else {
      random += adds[i].percent;
    }
  }
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('<img src="http://cdn.com/' + id + '.jpg" alt='' />');
});
db.on('load', function() {
  server.listen(80);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found these comparing Java to node.js, concerning performance:

http://www.olympum.com/java/quick-benchmark-java-nodejs/

http://www.olympum.com/java/java-aio-vs-nodejs/

They suggest Java is twice as fast, but do your own trials.

How many combinations of site, position, percent, etc. will you have? How many new dimensions will you add in the future?  Probably worth loading all of them at startup to avoid constantly hitting the database.  You could use the combination of them to build a key fast, which you lookup the address of the ad in memory.  This should be fast enough in Grails.

For thousands of requests a second, you are probably looking at a clustered farm, with a load balancer up front.  Depends on the complexity of the logic that builds the content of the page.

Once you have determined the URL which the browser should use to load the ad, I like the idea of a CDN, but that could get expensive!

If it were me, I would stick to the one technology (Grails) and iron out the problems as I face them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'm leaning towards sticking to grails. For starters we will have about 10.000-20.000 sites that each have 4 positions. So we're looking at around 40.000 to 80.000 database records. Shouldn't be too expensive to hold in memory with a key-value store like redis. 

I was thinking to beging with 2 grails instances behind a firewall, but that might be to few, I'm not sure. I'm new to the whole serve-content-fast-to-many-users scene..